# Touch began not operating correctly with sprite kit in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, action

Hello I am trying to make my first game to submit to the app store and when trying to use the touchesBegan: feature it just wouldn't work. I'll post my code below. Answers are very much appreciated. It has an error saying **Touch** was never used.

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

       for **touch**: AnyObject in touches {

    }
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the ** are for in your code but..

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
}
```

That should get you started with a simple touch handler. Your function definition doesn't quite look correct.

Comment: chris slowik the updated code you gave still will not work its says unidentified indetifier touch was never used before. please answer back

Comment: Unresolved identifier? what line does it give you that error on?

Comment: it says that on the line were you initiate the func. also when you added the constant it said that touch had never been used and that i should replace it with _

Comment: That's not an error.

After you get `touch` you need to do something with it. What are you trying to accomplish?

It's telling you that because you never use it.